# minecraft testfor @r[r=13] "/gamemode "that player" adventure"

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a command block that looks for a player in its radius, but wonder if I then can do this:

`/testfor @r[r=13] /gamemode adventure "the random player"`

Comment: What exactly do you want the command to do? Changing the game mode doesn't require a `testfor`. Also what version is this for?

Comment: Please specify what you actually want the command to do, because what you wrote there is not even close to being a correct command. Please also write what you tried yourself so far, because we expect some basic effort from askers, as said in the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No.

Slightly longer answer: `testfor` doesn't work this way, it only performs at test, and can't do anything with the result.  **Don't use `testfor` for anything other than debugging!**  (Or at all, since it was removed from the Java edition in version 1.13.)

But to actually answer you question, all you need to do to set a random player to adventure within a radius of 13 blocks is the following:

```
/gamemode adventure @r[r=13]
```

for Java edition versions 1.9 (1.8?) through 1.12 (and I believe this applies to Bedrock edition) or

```
/gamemode adventure @r[distance=..13]
```

for Java edition versions 1.13 and above.